# Why unary operators not allowed in compound assignments?

Tags: c

I know a!=b or a~=b etc compound assignments are not allowed in C though a=!b or a=~b is allowed. Just curious why the language was designed like that? Any specific technical reason? In latest compilers such support is provided? Such limitations of C (atleast I felt it is a limitation) makes the language complex for beginners. This makes us to by heart some of such features in C.

Comment: `a != b` already has a meaning — and it isn't an assignment.  In general, `a @= b` ( for a _binary_ operator `@`) is a shorthand for `a = a @ b` except that `a` is only evaluated once.  It doesn't make any sense for unary operators.  What would you use?  `a ~=` to achieve `a = ~a`?

Comment: `a = -b` is something else than `a -= b`. Aren't you arguing they should do the same thing?

Comment: Many of the unary operators either double as binary operators (`~`, `-`) or else already have a meaning when followed by an `=` (`!=`).  Even if that weren't the case, the syntax would be rather odd.  For instance, you'd have `x op=;` with nothing after it.  The closest C has to this are the pre- and post-increment operators `++` and `--`, which don't use `=` at all.

Comment: @TomKarzes: `+`, `-`, `*` and `&` are both unary and binary operators, but `~` and `!` are only unary operators, I believe.

Answer (score 0):

Defining `!=` and `~=` may cause unnecessary confusion, because some tokens can be either unary operator or binary operator, determined by the context. For example: What does `a -= b` mean, `a = a - b` or `a = -b`?

Any way, you don't need them. `a = !b` and `a = ~b` don't cause more typing, and are quite easy to understand.